# What to do in order to print 100?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wanted to print 100 as output in the below program.

I am getting 0 as answer.

```
    class s extends Thread{
    int j=0; 
        public void run() { 
            try{Thread.sleep(5000);} 
            catch(Exception e){} 
            j=100; 
        } 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            s t1=new s(); 
            t1.start(); 
            System.out.println(t1.j); 
        } 

}
```

Comment: Also, and correct me if I'm wrong gurus, rather than accessing the "s" class' variable directly you should include an accessor method to print the value of j.

Comment: @The Ox: That would be good practice. More important here is to synchronize access to `j` (or declare it `volatile`). It is possible (though unlikely) that the main thread could see a stale value of `j` even after the `s` thread has finished writing to it. See Brian Goetz's book "Java Concurrency in Practice" for a good explanation of why this is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have join the t1 to main.
So, the parent `thread(main())` will wait till the child thread is complete.

Answer (score 13):

You need to wait for the `Thread` to finish..I have added a call to [join](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) for you, which will block and wait for the `Thread` to complete before looking at the value of `j`:

```
class s extends Thread{
    int j=0; 
    public void run() { 
        try{ Thread.sleep(5000); } catch( Exception e ){} 
        j = 100; 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException { 
        s t1=new s(); 
        t1.start(); 
        t1.join() ; // Wait for t1 to finish
        System.out.println(t1.j); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What will change a synchronized block?

Comment: You really need to synchronize access to `j`, or to declare it `volatile`. It is possible to get a stale read even on primitive types. Brian Goetz can explain why better than I can. Still, +1 for giving the OP the right idea.

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably use something like FutureTask, or a framework like gpars or akka, but I felt that was outside the scope of the question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Join t1

```
t1.join
```

so that the main thread will wait

Answer (score 2):

Just join the thread t1 to main

```
t1.join
```